# Why did the dead breakfast club come back as ghosts?

Tags: plot-explanation, american-horror-story

In the halloween episodes from the first season of the *American Horror Story* we are presented with five students who later appeared to be dead, killed by Tate during the Westfield High massacre.

The show seems to imply that only people killed in immediate proximity of the house will be staying as ghosts. However, those five people were seemingly killed far enough from the house. So why is it that they came back as ghosts?

Answer (score 3):

They only came for the Halloween. Through the Halloween episodes, the theme of "boundary between the living and the dead is collapsing" is repeated multiple times.

Tate's victims only had that one night in the year to find him, ad it took them years to do so.

Also, you might be able to remember that they had to go once the sun was rising up...